# How to define input date in WHERE clause (MS Access DB)

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, where-clause

I have the following problem. Currently I'm using this SQL statement:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(Datum) AS DateField, Assets
FROM dbTable
WHERE Datum>=DateAdd("m",-12,Date())
GROUP BY Datum, ID, Assets
ORDER BY Datum DESC;
```

I need the last 12 months by the users input date, but I don't know how to define the input (e.g. #01.01.2017#) in the WHERE-clause?!

That means when the user select 01/01/2017 then the result need to be the all 12 months from last year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem as follows:

```
SELECT ID, Datum, Assets
FROM dbTable
WHERE Datum>=DateAdd("m",-12,#01/01/2017#) and Datum<=#01/01/2017# and ID=325
GROUP BY Datum, ID, Assets
ORDER BY Datum DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Date()
```

with

```
Forms!MyForm!MyCombo.Value
```

Comment: When I replace `Date()` with `#01/01/2017#` I always get the dates from 02/02/2017 until 04/01/2016

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to select Max(Datum) when you Group By Datum. Thus:

```
SELECT ID, Datum AS DateField, Assets
FROM dbTable
GROUP BY Datum, ID, Assets
HAVING Datum >= DateAdd("yyyy", -1, DateValue(Forms!YourForm!txtDatum))
ORDER BY Datum DESC;
```